# CSS Make last child to dynamically take width which left in parent

Tags: html, css, width

In my case childs number is returned from server side. In case there are less than 6 childs I need to add dummy child which would take left place of parent.

For example :

1 situation with two childs
[image]
2 situation with three childs
[image]

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6hgd55k/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="big-child"></div>
</div>
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
}

#container > div {
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.big-child {
    width: 59%!important;
    margin-right: 0px!important;
}
```

How could I achieve this with only CSS and withoud dinamically changing child width with javascript?

**UPDATE**

Found good [website](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) which generates CSS code depending on your boxes needs.

Comment: Any browser requirement/support?

Comment: In my project we support from IE10, Chrome and Firefox versions is not the case I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern browser you could use `flexbox`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyMgQL

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 syntax */
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gray;
}

#container > div {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#container > div.big-child {
   -ms-flex-grow: 1;  /* IE 10 syntax */
   flex-grow: 1;
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

---

Further info:
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox
(note that `IE10` is supported but it implements an older syntax)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use floats, you can use `overflow:hidden;` on the last child to force it to occupy the remaining space.

Alternative solutions could be to use `flexbox` (depending on your required browser support) or CSS tables.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#container > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
#container > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.child {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
}
.big-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<h4>Three Blocks</h4>
<div id="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="big-child"></div>
</div>

<h4>Two Blocks</h4>
<div id="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="big-child"></div>
</div>
```